# Alignment in equations

Tags: equations, align

I want to write two simple equations one below the other, but it seems that aligned environment aligns to the right and I want to align them to the left. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
S_1' (x_0) = S_n' (x_n) = 0 \quad \text{(clamped boundary conditions),} \quad \text{or} \\
S_1'' (x_0) = S_n'' (x_n) = 0 \quad \text{(natural boundary conditions)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

but I want `S_1''(x_0)` to appear directly below `S_1'(x_0)`, not to be moved to the left. Do you please know the solution?

Comment: You need to put alignment symbols, i.e. `&`, such that LaTeX knows how you wish to align.

Comment: since ypu've said in a comment that you are new to latex, a look at some basic documentation might help.  for `amsmath` (which defines `align`), type `texdoc amsmath` at a command line prompt.  a lot of other good (many more general) suggestions can be found at [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/579)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to left-align the material, you need to provide alignments points via `&` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&S_1' (x_0) = S_n' (x_n) = 0 \quad \text{(clamped boundary conditions), or} \\
&S_1'' (x_0) = S_n'' (x_n) = 0 \quad \text{(natural boundary conditions)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

The alignment points are marked with an `&`. If there are several groups (columns of alignments), a further `&` is used to introduce each new group (except the first group), so that n columns of alignment require 2n-1 ampersands.

Here you can use this code for instance:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
S_1' (x_0) &= S_n' (x_n) = 0 &&\text{(clamped boundary conditions),} \quad \text{or} \\
S_1'' (x_0) &= S_n'' (x_n) = 0 && \text{(natural boundary conditions)}
\end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

I also suggest these solutions based on `alignat*`, using the `\ArrowBetweenLines` command from `mathtools` (needless to load `amsmath` in this case), or `flalign*`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


\begin{alignat*}{3}
 & & S_1' (x_0) &= S_n' (x_n) = 0 &\quad & \text{(clamped boundary conditions),} \\
\ArrowBetweenLines[\text{or}]%
 & & S_1'' (x_0) &= S_n'' (x_n) = 0 & & \text{(natural boundary conditions)}
 \end{alignat*}

\begin{flalign*} 
& & S_1' (x_0) &= S_n' (x_n) = 0 &&\text{(clamped boundary conditions),} \\
& \text{or} & S_1'' (x_0) &= S_n'' (x_n) = 0 && \text{(natural boundary conditions)} 
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Three separate answers posted within 38 seconds of each other!

Comment: @Mico: That' s for the New Year :o)

Answer (score 8):

you forgot on anchors for align (ampersands) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
S_1' (x_0)  & = S_n' (x_n) = 0 \quad \text{(clamped boundary conditions),} \quad \text{or} \\
S_1'' (x_0) & = S_n'' (x_n) = 0 \quad \text{(natural boundary conditions)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all very much! I did not even know there are some anchors for alignment... :-) I am new to Latex.