# align two piecewise functions

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I have problem with my piecewise functions

I read others post and I tried this but I have errors

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    $x_{{i}{j}}$ = 
         &\begin{cases}
           \text{1,} &\quad\text{Si se envía agua desde área i ( i $\in$   \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}) a sitio j ( j $\in$  \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\})} \\
           \text{0,} &\quad\text{En caso contrario}
         \end{cases}\\
    $y_{j}$ = 
         &\begin{cases}
           \text{1,} &\quad\text{  Si se construye planta en el sitio j ( j $\in $   \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\})} \\
           \text{0,} &\quad\text{En caso contrario}
         \end{cases}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> Runaway argument?   ! Paragraph ended before \align* was complete.  
>                      \par  l.592

I did this (using **[**) and it works well but they appear not aligned

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[   
x_{{i}{j}} = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{1,} &\quad\text{Si se envía agua desde área i ( i $\in$   \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}) a sitio j ( j $\in$  \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\})} \\
       \text{0,} &\quad\text{En caso contrario}
     \end{cases}
\]
\[   
y_{j} = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{1,} &\quad\text{  Si se construye planta en el sitio j ( j $\in $   \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\})} \\
       \text{0,} &\quad\text{En caso contrario}
     \end{cases}
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

and I want they are aligned, like this

[image]

Comment: remove the `$$` around `x_{ij}` and `y_{j}`. `\begin{align*}` is already a math environment.

Comment: lol I did that and it didn't work before but now it works hahaha thanks man!! is there a way to align the functions using \[ .... \]  ?

Comment: Yes, with the `\begin{aligned}` environment from amsmath. E.g. of its use: [Alignment in equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408417/117534)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beware! `align` already typesets its contents in math mode (but `\text` reverts to text mode).

You have to just align the equals signs with `&=`; for the long line, I suggest a `tabular`. Some vertical spacing will help, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x_{ij} &=
  \begin{cases}
  1, &\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      Si se envía agua desde área $i$ ($i\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$) \\
      a sitio $j$ ($j\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$)
      \end{tabular} \\[4ex]
  0, &\text{En caso contrario}
\end{cases}\\
y_{j} &=
  \begin{cases}
  1, &\text{Si se construye planta en el sitio $j$ ($j\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$)} \\[1ex]
  0, &\text{En caso contrario}
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here it is I simplified the text part typing using the `cases*` environment from `mathtols` (needless to load àmsmath`). I had to dplit the first case to make it fit the margins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
    x_{{i}{j}} & =
         \begin{cases*}
           \text{1,} &\quad Si se envía agua desde área $ i\: ( i \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\})$ \\
             & \quad a sitio $ j\: ( j \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\})$ \\
           \text{0,} &\quad{En caso contrario}
         \end{cases*}\\[1.5ex]
   y_{j} & =
   \begin{cases*}
 1, &\quad Si se construye planta en el sitio $ j\: ( j \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\})$ \\
 0, &\quad En caso contrario
 \end{cases*}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If we go back to your original attempt, a few quick changes gives the result you wanted. This: removes the `$$` around `x_{ij}` and `y_j` and moves the `&` you use for alignment to align the equals signs. Edit: I also compressed the set notation to shorten the long line and returned `i` and `j` to math mode, as you currently have them as subscripts in math mode. If you'd prefer them to be set upright you should change the subscripts as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
x_{ij} &=
\begin{cases}
\text{1,} &\quad\text{Si se envía agua desde área $i$ ($i \in \{1,2,\dots,10\}$) a sitio $j$ ($j \in \{1,2,\dots,7\}$)} \\
\text{0,} &\quad\text{En caso contrario}
\end{cases}\\
y_{j} &= 
\begin{cases}
\text{1,} &\quad\text{  Si se construye planta en el sitio $j$ ($j \in \{1,2,\dots,7\}$)} \\
\text{0,} &\quad\text{En caso contrario}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: New aligned output]

Comment: Since `i` and `j` are used in math mode on the LHS, it seems appropriate to use `$i$ ($i \in \{1,\dots,10\}$)` and `$j$ ($j \in \{1,\dots,7\}$)` on the RHS.

Comment: Good point, as is the compression of the set notation. Edits made.